# Tensor notation about $A^Tx$

Tags: notation, tensors

I can express $x=x^ie_i$ and $x^T$ by $x_ie^i$. But how to express $A^Tx$ where $A=a^i_je_i\otimes e^j$? I don't think I can write as $a^j_ix^i$ or $a^j_ix^j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $x = x^i\mathbf e_i$, and the elements of $A$ are $A^i{}_j$, then $A^Tx$ must be $x^iA^i{}_j\mathbf e_j$. The usual rule that each dummy index pair must have one index "up" and one "down" gets reversed because you're specifying the *transpose* of $A$.

If you want to follow the rule strictly (which you should if your tensors may transform non-orthogonally), you need to insert some explicit index raisings and lowerings, i.e.
$$ x^iA_i{}^j \mathbf e_j = x^ig_{ip}A^p{}_qg^{qj}\mathbf e_j$$
where $g$ (following general relativity conventions) expresses your chosen isomorphism between vectors and covectors (that is, the inner product).

Comment: Thanks. But when you write $x^iA_i{}^je_j$, I still regard it as $Ax$. How do you discern that?

Comment: @zhangwfjh: No, $Ax$ would be $x^iA^j{}_i\mathbf e_j$. The order of the indices on the $A$ matters. In $Ax$, the dummy index on $x$ matches the _right_ index on $A$.

Answer (score 0):

What about $B = \delta_{jk} \delta^{il} a^k_l e_i \otimes e^j$?

Comment: Sorry, could you see my update?

Comment: Well, you know how to multiply matrices using Einstein convention, don't you?

Comment: I think I know that well. Summation is implicitly taken over repeated indices.

Comment: So, now you know the expressions of $A^T$, you should be able to work it out.

Answer (score 0):

Using Einstein summation notation,
$$
\begin{align}
b^k_\ell = \delta_{i \ell} \delta^{j k} a^i_j.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Sorry, could you see my update?